# CSS Grid container with dynamic amount of columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid container with those settings -

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 2fr repeat(4, 1fr) 2rem;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
```

I initially set the container for 8 columns. The issue is that in some cases will be 9 columns. The extra column will be added to be the 3rd and not at the end, so after the insertion of the extra column the grid should be -

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 2fr repeat(4, 1fr) 2rem;
```

Here is the code

```js
function addColumn(){
  var g = document.querySelector(".my_grid");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("id", "column9");
  g.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.my_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 2fr repeat(4, 1fr) 2rem;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.my_grid div{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .5s linear all;
}

#column1 { background: #0000 }
#column2 { background: #0001 }
#column3 { background: #0002 }
#column4 { background: #0003 }
#column5 { background: #0004 }
#column6 { background: #0005 }
#column7 { background: #0006 }
#column8 { background: #0007 } 
#column9 { background: #0008; border:1px solid red; }

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_grid">
  <div id="column1"></div>
  <div id="column2"></div>
  <div id="column3"></div>
  <div id="column4"></div>
  <div id="column5"></div>
  <div id="column6"></div>
  <div id="column7"></div>
  <div id="column8">
    2rem
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="addColumn()">Add Column</button>
```

So the question is how to handle this situation? I tried to set it dynamically with auto-fill but it doesn't work.

Comment: plain css can never be parsed backwards. so the parent can't change based on the children. thats one of the fundamental designs of css to stay performant. I am afraid you would need a js-script to count the children and set a class on the parent.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought, thanks!

Comment: does it have to be grid or could you use flex?

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on order property and the creation of implicit extra column at the start. The trick is to use nth-child to consider the case where there is 9 items in order to:

- Place the first item outside the explicit grid. It will use the implicit one (1fr will be added at the start)
- Place the last item column9 at the beginning.
- Force the item column2 to be before column9

```js
function addColumn(){
  var g = document.querySelector(".my_grid");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("id", "column9");
  g.appendChild(div);
  document.querySelector("button").style.display="none";
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.my_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 2fr repeat(4, 1fr) 2rem;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; /* our implicit column */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.my_grid div{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .5s linear all;
}

#column1 { background: #0000 }
#column2 { background: #0001 }
#column3 { background: #0002 }
#column4 { background: #0003 }
#column5 { background: #0004 }
#column6 { background: #0005 }
#column7 { background: #0006 }
#column8 { background: #0007 }
#column9 {
  background: #0008; 
  border:1px solid red;
  order:-1; /* place at the start */
}

/* The below will trigger only with 9 columns */
#column1:first-child:nth-last-child(9) {
  background:green;
  grid-column:-10; /* place before everything outisde the explicit grid */
}
#column2:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(8) {
  background:blue;
  order:-1; /* place before column9*/
}


button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_grid">
  <div id="column1"></div>
  <div id="column2"></div>
  <div id="column3"></div>
  <div id="column4"></div>
  <div id="column5"></div>
  <div id="column6"></div>
  <div id="column7"></div>
  <div id="column8">
    2rem
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="addColumn()">Add Column</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right you want to add a dynamic div or there is a div that is added to the end. Here is how you can make it be in the third place.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.my_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 2fr repeat(4, 1fr) 2rem;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.my_grid div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
}

#column1 {
  background: #0000;
}

#column2 {
  background: #0001;
}

#column3 {
  background: #0002;
}

#column4 {
  background: #0003;
}

#column5 {
  background: #0004;
}

#column6 {
  background: #0005;
}

#column7 {
  background: #0006;
}

#column8 {
  background: #0007;
}

#column9 {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_grid">
  <div id="column1"></div>
  <div id="column2"></div>
  <div id="column3"></div>
  <div id="column4"></div>
  <div id="column5"></div>
  <div id="column6"></div>
  <div id="column7"></div>
  <div id="column8"></div>
  <div id="column9"></div>
</div>
```